# How to test for a List in Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

As far as I can see, there is no way to test if an object is a `List` instance in Jinja2.

Is that correct and has anyone implemented a custom test/extension in Jinja2?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can easily do this whit a custom filter in jinja2.

First create you test method:

```
def is_list(value):
    return isinstance(value, list)
```

And add it as an custom filter:

```
j = jinja2.Jinja2(app)
j.environment.filters.update({
        'is_list': is_list,
})
```

Answer (score 106):

I did it like this:

```
{% if var is iterable and (var is not string and var is not mapping) %}
```

You can find a list of all jinja tests [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests).

Comment: in my case `{% if var is string %}` worked perfectly; thank you.

Comment: For me this catches also dictionaries.

Comment: Just add a test for mapping
 `{% if var is iterable and (var is not string and var is not mapping) -%}`

Answer (score 14):

Iterable return True also on dict.
Try this:

```
{% if var.__class__.__name__ == 'list' %}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my setup, I'd like for a value to either be a string or list of strings coming into the Jinja template.  So really what I cared about wasn't string vs list, but single item vs multiple items.  This answer might help if your use case is similar.

Since there isn't a built-in test for "is list?" that also rejects strings, I borrowed a pattern from API design and wrapped the single objects in a list on the Python side then checked list length on the Jinja side.

Python:

```
context = { ... }

# ex. value = 'a', or ['a', 'b']
if not isinstance(value, list):
    value = [value]

context['foo'] = value
```

Jinja:

```
{% if foo|length == 1 %}
  single-item list
{% elif foo|length > 1 %}
  multi-item list
{% endif %}
```

And if all you want to do is add an item separator for display purposes, you can skip the explicit length check and just `{{ value|join(', ') }}`.

Answer (score -1):

Jinja has many builtin tests. You are probably looking for [iterable](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#iterable).

```
{% if var is iterable %}
```

Comment: I noticed the `sequence` test too but it also considers a string a sequence.

Comment: i agree -- this doesn't work, you need {% if var is iterable and var is not string %}