# Python Template, checking for variable value type for iteration

Tags: python, templates, flask

Say that I have this dictionary

```
{"k1":"dog", "k2":"cat", "k3":["Pochi","Wanwan"]}
```

Now in my template, I'm iterating like so:

```
{% for key, value in dict.iteritems() %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But I do want to do some additional processing within the  tags, is it possible to check if "value" is of a list or dictionary type? So that instead of just spitting out the list, I could do things like, say bullet them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if "value" is of a dictionary type you could do something like

```
{% for key, value in dict.iteritems() %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ key }}</td>
    {% if value is mapping %}
        "Do something"
    {% else %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

To check if "value" is of a list type, you could create a custom filter. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947325/testing-for-a-list-in-jinja2) a link you would find useful.

Edit: Here's an example of how you would create a custom filter. First the function

```
def is_list(value):
    return isinstance(value, list)
```

Then declare the function as a filter

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
....
app.jinja_env.filters['is_list'] = is_list
```

Then the filter will be available in your template.

Comment: The provided link seems to hold the answer for list checking, but it doesn't seem like my jinja2 module's finding Jinja2 :( Any alternatives? Nevermind, just saw your edit

Comment: Just tested this, the issue with that is that strings are also iterable hah. So I would get a string chopped up by characters.

Comment: Oops didn't think of that. I think custom filter is the way to go then. Did you try creating one? It's quite easy.

Comment: Tried creating a custom filter but python started yelling at me when I tried jinja2.Jinja2(app), seems like Jinja2 isn't in my module :s

Comment: I would use the filter like so right? {% if value is is_filter %}

Comment: To use filters, you'll need to use the | symbol. So, it would be like `{% if value|is_list %} `.

Comment: It doesn't seem like env=jinja2.Environment()->env.filters.... is adding the filter to the context. Getting no filter named 'is_list' when it tries to render the template :(

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try adding the filter directly to your app.